# addeventlistener to a dynamically generated element triggers event on all dynamically generated elements after him

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage where I have added the possibility of highlighting specific parts of texts. Whenever I select some text and press ctrl+c, the text selected is inserted into a span and highlighted. 
The HTML looks like that when an element is highlighted.

```
  <div id ="text">
      <p>
    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci "<span class="highlight" id="0">luctus</span>
 "et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;" </p>
```

I'm trying to create a functionality to change the highlighted colour when the span is clicked on.

To do so, i created a function below called everytime a new element is highlighted. It selects all spans within the text, supposedly selects the relevant span thanks to its ID to change its class, and adds the event listener.

```
function eventHighlighted() {

  //select all spans within the text into an HTML collection.
  let textToAnnotate = document.querySelector('#text');
  let spansExisting = textToAnnotate.querySelectorAll('span');    

 // function to change the highlighted colour
  function changeColour () {
    let selectedText = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight")[this.id];
    selectedText.className = "highlight-clicked";
    }

// add eventListener to all spans.
  for (var i = 0; i < spansExisting.length; i++) {
     var existingSpan = spansExisting[i];
     existingSpan.addEventListener("click", changeColour);
     }
  }
```

This function is called everytime a new bit of text is highlighted. (I gather this is not very memory efficient, as it can possibly add unnecessary event listeners on some spans that don't need one anymore.)

The problem i have is that it works nicely for the first element highlighted. Whenever i click on this bit of highlighted text, the highlight changes colour.

However, when I highlight a second bit of text, for instance with this example

```
 <div id ="text">
          <p>
        Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci "<span class="highlight" id="0">luctus</span>
     "et ultrices" <span class="highlight" id="1">posuere cubilia</span> " Curae;" </p>
```

if i clicks on the first span (luctus), it will trigger the class change on it but also on the second span below. 
When i select the second one, however, it will work as expected and only trigger the class change on the second span.

I cannot really figure out why. I gather my function triggered on the first span actually instructs him to change the class for all spans within the HTML collection. I don't understand why it does not does instruct him to do this specifically only for him.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an extra attribute in span tags. Take a look at my solution. Hope this helps.

```js
function initHighlights() {
  var highlights = document.querySelectorAll('.highlight');

  for (var i = 0; i < highlights.length; i++) {
    highlights[i].onclick = function() {
      // this - refers to span HTMLElement
      this.classList.toggle("highlight-clicked");
    };
  }
}

initHighlights();
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.highlight-clicked {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id ="text">
    <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci "<span class="highlight">luctus</span>"et ultrices <span class="highlight">posuere cubilia</span> Curae;"</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain me though what was happening in my initial coding piece?  I'm curious to understand the logic behind it.